# Vector indexes.

Tags: notation

For a vector of two dimensions I can use $\vec x = (x_a, x_b)$ or $\vec x = (x_x, x_y)$, if no letters are more appropriate.

What if I need to name more dimensions than letters in the alphabet? What's better, $\vec x = (x_0, x_1, x_2, ... x_{29})$, or $\vec x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, ... x_{30})$? If none is better than the other, which one's most used, and why?

Comment: They are equally good and the second one is more common.

Comment: You could also start using letters from the Greek, Cyrillic, Hebrew and other alphabets. You can use upper case letters, and script letters. But my personal preference would be to take the approach advocated in https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/330.On_Beyond_Zebra_

Answer (score 1):

Usually the following is adopted for $\vec x\in \mathbb R^n$

$$\vec x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_{n})$$

but you can use also other notations declaring that in order to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 1):

We *usually* don't care whether indices start at $0$ or $1$ (except in the sense we'd rather start with our favourite if it doesn't matter, and the old joke is that [set theorists start at $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers#Definition_as_von_Neumann_ordinals) and non-[Peano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation) number theorists [start at $1$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html)). I say *usually*, because there are a few cases where we do:

- If you're working in a Riemannian geometry with one dimension having the wrong sign to make the usual Euclidean contribution to the squared norm on vectors, it makes sense to [put that Cartesian coordinate at the start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Tangent_vectors), and conventionally its index is $0$. While sci-fi often calls time the fourth dimension, physicists tend to think of it as the zeroth. (That being said, occasional texts make time $x_4$ rather than $x_0$, or perhaps that should be $x^0$, but that's another story.)
- If the $i$th entry of a vector, or $ij$ entry of a matrix etc., is to be written as a function of the index or indices, use a convention that simplifies things. For example, the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) should start at $0$ (actually, that's a good idea with sequences in general), as should [ladder-operator matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators#Matrix_representation).
- If there's programming involved, use the same indexing for your mathematical exposition as in the code itself, [which varies by language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering#Usage_in_programming_languages). For example, Python starts at $0$, whereas R starts at $1$.

Comment: @85579 Thank you for your comments; I've added four links.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/116616/108880